# Django AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute '_last_executed'

Tags: python, django

I have an error when run migration file in Django 1.5.12 with python 2.7.10 and  South 0.8.4

Database Mysql@5.7

Database mysql driver : mysqlclient@1.3.14

My `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

My commands

1. ./manage.py schemamigration polls --initial

-> It will create the initial migration file

2. ./manage.py migrate polls

-> Error here .

```
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute '_last_executed'
```

Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Why are you using such an old, unsupported and insecure version of Django?

Comment: my company project is using this old version python. Therefore I am learning to understand how to use it

Comment: Please edit your post to add the full traceback (and eventually read it while you're at it - it may contain the informations you need to debug this). Also add the database vendor and version and the database connector package and version.

Comment: It's full traceback I receive from the terminal. I added the database info

Comment: @ToujouAya what you posted is NOT the "full traceback", it's just the error message. The full traceback will include all the call stack etc.

Comment: My mistake. I have enabled DEBUG, DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS, and TEMPLATE_DEBUG but I can't see the full traceback. What should I do to get the full traceback?

Comment: Note that there are quite a few reports about this error: https://gitlab.com/ammaranjith/mayan-edms/issues/8 - http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Django-South-MySQL-bug-td4994248.html - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18592 (just to name a few).

Comment: "I can't see the full traceback" => you should have it in your console when running the migration...

Comment: Sound strange because my console only has that message. No full traceback